# I am trying to create a vacation scheduler in React Material-Ui

Tags: material-ui, scheduler, react-typescript

I made a grid using the table component from material-ui, and i want to make a bar that will show the range from startDate to endDate for each employee, the bar should span across table cells but i have no idea how to make that happen

```
import { Button, Popover, Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableContainer, TableHead, TableRow,  TextField, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getSelectedDate } from '../../../store/redux/reducers/monthPickerSlice';
import { RootState } from '../../../store/redux/store';
import { getDaysOfTheMonth } from '../../../store/utils/worklogUtils';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { Employee } from '../../../store/types/utils/VacationTypes';
import DeckIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Deck';
import CheckIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Check';

interface VacationTableProps {
dummyEmployeeData: Employee[];
}

const VacationTable: React.FC<VacationTableProps> = ({ dummyEmployeeData }) => {
const selectedDate = dayjs(useSelector((state: RootState) => getSelectedDate(state)));
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null);
const [selectedEmployee, setSelectedEmployee] = useState<Employee | null>(null);
const [selectedDateCell, setSelectedDateCell] = useState<string | null>(null);
const [comment, setComment] = useState<string>('');
const [endDateValue, setEndDateValue] = useState<string | null>(null);

const { t } = useTranslation();

interface Employee {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    startDate: string;
    endDate: string;
}

const handleLastCellClick = (employee: Employee, date: string) => (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLTableCellElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    setSelectedEmployee(employee);
    setSelectedDateCell(date);
};

const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    setSelectedEmployee(null);
    setSelectedDateCell(null);
    setEndDateValue(null);
};

const handleCommentChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setComment(event.target.value);
};

const getVacationBars = (employee: Employee, cellDate: string) => {
    const vacationBars: React.ReactNode[] = [];
    const vacationStartDate = dayjs(employee.startDate);
    const vacationEndDate = dayjs(employee.endDate);

    const isVacationDay =
        dayjs(cellDate).isAfter(vacationStartDate) && dayjs(cellDate).isBefore(vacationEndDate) || dayjs(cellDate).isSame(vacationStartDate) || dayjs(cellDate).isSame(vacationEndDate);

    if (isVacationDay) {
        vacationBars.push(
            <div
                key={cellDate}
                className="vacation-bar"
            ></div>
        );
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return vacationBars;
};

const calculateVacationCount = (date: string): number => {
    let count = 0;

    dummyEmployeeData.forEach((employee) => {
        const vacationStartDate = dayjs(employee.startDate);
        const vacationEndDate = dayjs(employee.endDate);

        if (
            dayjs(date).isAfter(vacationStartDate) &&
            dayjs(date).isBefore(vacationEndDate)
        ) {
            count++;
        } else if (
            dayjs(date).isSame(vacationStartDate) ||
            dayjs(date).isSame(vacationEndDate)
        ) {
            count++;
        }
    });

    return count;
};

const calculateTotalVacationCount = () => {
    let totalCount = 0;

    dummyEmployeeData.forEach((employee) => {
        const vacationStartDate = dayjs(employee.startDate);
        const vacationEndDate = dayjs(employee.endDate);

        // Iterate over all days of the month and accumulate the count
        getDaysOfTheMonth(selectedDate).forEach((day) => {
            if (
                dayjs(day.date).isAfter(vacationStartDate) &&
                dayjs(day.date).isBefore(vacationEndDate)
            ) {
                totalCount++;
            } else if (
                dayjs(day.date).isSame(vacationStartDate, 'day') ||
                dayjs(day.date).isSame(vacationEndDate, 'day')
            ) {
                totalCount++;
            }
        });
    });

    return totalCount;
};

return (
    <TableContainer
        sx={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            border: 0,
            color: 'text.main',
            borderColor: 'background.lighter',
            '::-webkit-scrollbar': {
                height: '6px',
                width: '6px',
                bgcolor: 'background.lighter',
                borderRadius: '10px',
            },
            '::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
                bgcolor: 'background.lightest',
                borderRadius: '10px',
            },
        }}
    >
        <Table
            sx={{
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                tableLayout: 'fixed', // Ensure that the table layout is fixed
                position: 'relative', // Set position to relative for pseudo-elements
            }}
            size="small"
            stickyHeader
        >
            <TableHead sx={{ height: '50px' }}>
                <TableRow style={{ position: 'sticky', top: 0, zIndex: 1, background: '#fff' }}>
                    <TableCell
                        sx={{
                            width: '150px',
                            borderRight: '1px solid',
                            borderRightColor: 'background.lighter',
                            position: 'relative', // Set position to relative for pseudo-elements
                            '::after': {
                                // Pseudo-element for vertical grid lines
                                content: "''",
                                position: 'absolute',
                                top: 0,
                                right: 0,
                                bottom: 0,
                                width: '1px',
                                background: 'background.lighter',
                            },
                            alignItems: 'center',
                        }}
                    >
                        {t('page.projects.detailsView.employee')}
                    </TableCell>
                    {getDaysOfTheMonth(selectedDate).map((day, index) => (
                        <TableCell
                            key={index}
                            sx={{
                                width: 'calc((100% - 150px) / ' + getDaysOfTheMonth(selectedDate).length + ')',
                                position: 'relative', // Set position to relative for pseudo-elements
                                alignItems: 'left',
                                top: 0, // Ensure the cell stays at the top of the sticky row
                                zIndex: 1, // Ensure the cell is above other elements when scrolling
                                background: '#fff', // Match the background color of the row
                            }}
                        >
                            <Typography sx={{ width: "22px", fontSize: '9px' }}>
                                <span style={{ color: '#000000' }}>{day.date.format('DD')}</span>{' '}
                                <span style={{ color: '#999999' }}>{day.date.format('dd')[0]}</span>
                            </Typography>
                        </TableCell>
                    ))}
                </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
                {dummyEmployeeData.map((empData) => (
                    <TableRow sx={{ height: "50px", maxHeight: "50px" }}>
                        <TableCell sx={{ borderRight: "1px solid", borderBottom: 0, borderRightColor: 'background.lighter', }}>
                            {empData.name}
                        </TableCell>
                        {getDaysOfTheMonth(selectedDate).map((day) => (
                            <TableCell
                                onClick={(event) => {
                                    handleLastCellClick(empData, day.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))(event);
                                }}
                                sx={{
                                    borderRight:
                                        !getVacationBars(empData, day.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')) ||
                                        day.date.isSame(dayjs(empData.endDate), 'day')
                                            ? '1px dashed'
                                            : '0px',
                                    borderRightColor: 'background.lighter',
                                    backgroundColor: day.date.day() === 6 || day.date.day() === 0 ? '#eeeeee' : 'transparent',
                                    overflow: "hidden",
                                    alignItems: "left",
                                    paddingLeft: '0',
                                    transition: 'background-color 0.3s', // Add a transition    for hover effect
                                    cursor: 'pointer', // Set cursor to pointer for click interaction
                                    '&:hover': {
                                        backgroundColor: '#c2c2c2', // Change background   color on hover
                                    },
                                    '&:active': {
                                        backgroundColor: '#9f9f9f', // Change background color on click
                                    },
                                }}
                            >
                                {getVacationBars(empData, day.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))}
                            </TableCell>
                        ))}
                    </TableRow>
                ))}
                <TableRow style={{ position: 'sticky', top: 0, zIndex: 1, background: '#fff' }}>
                    <TableCell sx={{ height: "71px", borderTop: "1px solid", borderTopColor: 'background.lighter', }}>
                        <Typography>
                            {t('page.vacationView.sum')} / {t('page.vacationView.day')}
                        </Typography>
                    </TableCell>
                    {getDaysOfTheMonth(selectedDate).map((day, index) => (
                        <TableCell
                            key={index}
                            sx={{
                                width: 'calc((100% - 150px) / ' + getDaysOfTheMonth(selectedDate).length + ')',
                                background: '#fff',
                                position: 'relative',
                                textAlign: 'center',
                                top: 0,
                                zIndex: 1,
                            }}
                        >
                            {calculateVacationCount(day.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')) === 0 ? '-  ' : calculateVacationCount(day.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))}
                        </TableCell>
                    ))}
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow style={{ position: 'sticky', bottom: 0, zIndex: 2, background:   '#fff' }}>
                    <TableCell sx={{ height: "71px" }}>
                        <Typography>
                            {t('page.vacationView.sum')}
                        </Typography>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell
                        colSpan={getDaysOfTheMonth(selectedDate).length}
                        sx={{
                            width: 'calc((100% - 150px) / ' +   getDaysOfTheMonth(selectedDate).length + ')',
                            position: 'relative',
                            textAlign: 'center',
                            top: 0,
                            zIndex: 2,
                            background: '#fff',
                        }}>
                        <Typography>
                            {calculateTotalVacationCount() + " "}
                            <span style={{ color: '#999999' }}>{t('page.vacationView.days')}.  </span>
                        </Typography>
                    </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            </TableBody>
        </Table>
        <Popover
            id={id}
            open={open}
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            onClose={handleClose}
            anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'bottom',
                horizontal: 'left',
            }}
            transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
            }}
            PaperProps={{
                style: {
                    width: '683px', // Adjust the width as needed (3 times wider than the   original)
                    maxHeight: '310px',
                    borderRadius: "4px",// Adjust the max height as needed
                    overflow: "hidden"
                },
            }}
        >
            <div style={{ padding: '0px' }}>
                <TableContainer sx={{ border: "0px", padding: "10px", paddingTop: "3px" }}>
                    <TableRow sx={{ width: "660px", borderBottom: "1px solid" }}>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Typography variant="h6">
                                {selectedEmployee?.name}
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="body1" sx={{ color: "grey" }}>
                                <DeckIcon sx={{ color: "grey", fontSize: "15px" }} /> {selectedDateCell ? (endDateValue ? (selectedDateCell === endDateValue ? selectedDateCell + " " + "-" + " " + "..." : selectedDateCell + " - " + endDateValue) : selectedDateCell + " " + "-" + " " + "...") : ''}
                            </Typography>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" sx={{ marginTop:    '10px', left: "170px", width: "130px" }}>
                                <CheckIcon sx={{ fontSize: "15px", right: "13px", position:          "relative" }} />
                                Save
                            </Button>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell sx={{ borderBottom: "0px" }}>
                            <TextField
                                required
                                id="outlined-required"
                                type="date"
                                label="End Date"
                                defaultValue={selectedDateCell}
                                onChange={(e) => { setEndDateValue(e.currentTarget.value) }}
                                sx={{ width: "300px" }}
                            />
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell sx={{ borderBottom: "0px" }}>
                            <TextField
                                select
                                id="outlined-required"
                                type="outlined-select-currency"
                                label="Category"
                                sx={{ width: "300px" }}
                            />
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell
                            colSpan={2}
                            sx={{ borderBottom: "0px" }}
                        >
                            <TextField
                                sx={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
                                id="outlined-comment"
                                label="Comment"
                                multiline
                                rows={4}
                                variant="outlined"
                                value={comment}
                                onChange={handleCommentChange}
                            />
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableContainer>
            </div>
        </Popover>
    </TableContainer>
);
};

export default VacationTable;
```

How would i go about creating a component that will be able to seamlessly span across these cells instead of generating a button in each cell in the vacation range period, and making it look seamless with css?